# I've changed default shell but my terminal don't get it

Tags: command-line

Recently I've changed my default shell from bash to zsh like this:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh myname
```

But when I invoke a new terminal (e.g. using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) I still have bash loaded:

```
myname@machine:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep myname
myname:x:1000:1000:myname,,,:/home/myname:/bin/zsh
myname@machine:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

zsh **is** installed and can be explicitly runned with `zsh` command.
How to deal with that?

Comment: log out and log back in?

Comment: btw.: A useless use of cat. Grep expects a filename, if you don't feed it from stdin: `grep myname /etc/password` would be the natural way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/passwd` file. In terminal type

`gksu gedit /etc/passwd`

Find out line containing your user name. Change `/bin/bash` to `/bin/zsh`.

Logout and Login again. Now zsh will be default. See the below image

[image: zsh]

Comment: line with my name is already set to `/bin/zsh` as I showed in second listing

Comment: I just tested in my system. Its working after logout and login

Comment: yes, I've logged out and in, and it's all works. I've got used to instant changes on new terminal window after my edits  of `.bashrc` and forget that this is not working that way with user information.

Comment: If anyone else reaches this page and doesn't want to log in and log out again to see the shell change working, use the command `su - myname` to open a session with the new shell, using an existing terminal window.